# Loading a ViewController from Swift Framework

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, ios-frameworks

I am creating a `Swift framework` which has `ABC.Storyboard` and one `ViewController`. I have referenced all the `UIView` to `MyViewController` which is also present in Framework.
When I add this framework to my app and try to load this `MyViewController` , I get  **setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key myImageView** error.

Comment: what is the framework to be added?

Comment: @IyyappanRavi I have created my own Framework

Comment: I think you are missing any class name or seuge identifier name, check your storyboard or XIB

Comment: @IyyappanRavi have checked , naming is proper problem is when it tried to load UIView(UITextView and ImageView) which I have made connection with MyViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hitesh,

This happens only when your storyboard has stale information about the IBOutlets of its views.

**How it happened?**

You must be having an ImageView in your Storyboard's ViewController (MyViewController). Sometime during your development of the framework you have dragged an IBOutlet to the owner class (lets say MyViewController.swift) with the name `myImageView`

Later at somepoint you must have deleted the property named `myImageView` from your ownerClass (MyViewController.swift) and forgot to remove the reference from the storyboard to that property.

**What Happens?**

Your Storyboard's ViewController is still under the assumption that there is a property named `myImageView` in its ownerClass and it is an `IBOutlet` for its component `ImageView`.

So when the view is loaded it looks for that property when property not found it throws you error that this class is  *not coding-compliant for the key myImageView* because it failed to locate property named `myImageView`.

**Solution**

Open your storyboard select the MyViewController go to Connection inspector (click the last option on the right side which will show you the IBOutlets for each component in the ViewController) select your ImageView you will find something like this,
[image]

Click on the small 'x' symbol infront of the (myImageView) - (x MyViewController) to unlink it from the deleted property reference :) Clean the build and re run :)

Ta daaa problem solved :) happy coding :)